# Regular ternary ordered tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, graph-connectivity

I’m not too familiar with ordered tree. I’m solving excercise about tree but i’m not sure it is right or wrong

How many regular ternary ordered tree with height 3 (ordered tree means children of each vertex are assigned a fixed ordering)?
What is the smallest and biggest radius for tree with height k?

Attempt:
For regular ternary ordered tree with height 3
There will be 9 node that will have children: 
9C1 +9C2+9C3+9C4+9C4+9C5+9C6+9C7+9C8+9C9

Ordered tree with height of 3 , the total possibility tree are 511.
Because all sum possible combination of 9Ck (1<=k<=9) =511

Or other way multiplication of possibility in each subtree from level 1. First subtree will be 3C0 +3C1+3C2+3C3= 8 , because there are 3 subtree in height 1 so 8x8x8=512-1=511 , why substract 1 because 9C0 makes tree height 2

And smallest and biggest radius for tree with height k will be k for radius and 2k for diameter

Is this right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you've undercounted trees of height 3. Moreover, I don't have any idea what your "9 nodes that will have children" are.

This is an example of a regular ternary ordered tree of height 3:

```
  o
 /|\
o o o
 /|\
o o o
 /|\
o o o
```

I think there are almost 1000 different regular ternary ordered trees of height 3.

Note also that this example has radius 2.

Comment: This example is commonly known as a Christmas tree.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I didn't know that. I just chose it because it's easy to do in ASCII art.

Comment: Thankyou for answering my questions.  I add picture of tree with height 3, in height two there are 9 nodes , from that i choose where i choose where to put the children , it could be 1 subtree or 2 subtree with three tree until 9 subtree in height 3 . Is this makes sense?

Comment: @fiksx, but what if (as in my example) some of those nodes are missing?

Comment: @PeterTaylor yes you right, i was thinking to add that too..but not sure, is it possible to use combination..?

Comment: @fiksx, I don't see how to do it elegantly with that approach. But there is an elegant solution based on the recursive composition. And that's about as much of a hint as I want to give.

Comment: @PeterTaylor im thinking once again , and i got  3C1*(3C1+3C2+3C3)+3C2(6C1+6C2+6C3+6C4+6C5+6C6)+3C3(9C1+9C2+9C3+9C4+9C5+9C6+9C7+9C8+9C9)= 700 where 3C1 for the second level , is this quite right?

Comment: @fiksx, no, it should be much closer to 1000. Thinking in terms of combinations works for height 2, because each child of the root is either the unique tree of height 0 or the unique tree of height 1, but it doesn't work for height > 2.